# Drawing straight line between two points

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I would like my code to give me something similar to the picture but my intersecting straight does not want to move above or below the variable 1 and when I try to get it look exact like my picture it shifts away from my coordinates.

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$R_{pe}$}; 
    \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,2) node[above] {$R_{ph}$};
    \draw[->] (-2,1) -- (2,1);
    \draw[->] (1,-1.5) -- (1,2);
    \draw[blue] (0,1)  -- (1,0) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable: it's much easier for people to help you, if you complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Don't use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` inside `figure` or `table` environments. Just use `\begin{figure}\centering...\end{figure}`

Answer (score 4):

I don't really understand what your explanation of what goes wrong, but it's just a matter of choosing the proper coordinates I suppose. The slope of your blue line is -1, so you can for example start the line at (-1,2) instead of (0,1), and end it at (2,-1) instead of (1,0).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$R_{pe}$}; 
    \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,2) node[above] {$R_{ph}$};
    \draw[->] (-2,1) -- (2,1);
    \draw[->] (1,-1.5) -- (1,2);
    \draw[blue] (-1,2)  -- (2,-1) node[right,black] {$R_0=\dots$};
    \node at (0.25,0.25) {I};
    \node at (0.75,0.75) {II};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2):

Choosing the proper coordinates, as suggested by Torbjørn T.s answer is probably the best way to deal with your requirements. But if you don't insist on the blue line going exactly from the top of the vertical lines to the right of the horizontal lines, you can use `shorten` with negative lengths to extend the line.

Remark: In the example here I choose `-3cm` to better show the limitations, although `-4cm` would fit much better. And that length depens on the `scale` you're using.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$R_{pe}$}; 
\draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,2) node[above] {$R_{ph}$};
\draw[->] (-2,1) -- (2,1);
\draw[->] (1,-1.5) -- (1,2);
% -4cm for shorten is better, but set to -3cm to show the limitations
\draw[blue,shorten >=-3cm,shorten <=-3cm] (0,1)  -- (1,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit: As Torbjørn T. mentioned, a downside to this is, that nodes can't be easily added to the end of the line.** Using

```
\draw[blue,shorten >=-3cm,shorten <=-3cm] (0,1)  -- (1,0) node[right]{foo};
```

will lead to this:

[image]

Comment: A potential downside to this is node placement, try `\draw[blue,shorten >=-3cm,shorten <=-3cm] (0,1)  -- (1,0) node[right]{foo};`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. you're right. I added this to my answer.